# Music reactive LED brightness

Tags: transistors, led, music

I want to build a vactrol. That means I have to build a device that converts the incoming audio signal into brightness levels. I found [this.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/307994/regulating-led-brightness-using-headphone-output)

I tried building this:

[image]

This does not seem to work. The LED does not change its brightness.

Do you have an idea what could be the problem or do you have a better idea?

Comment: What are the characteristics of your input signal and what is providing it?

Comment: What wires did you connect between your headphone output and your circuit? Did you connect shield to battery negative (ground on your schematic)?

Comment: The audio signal comes from my computer and ranges around +0.5V and -0.5V

Comment: I wired the right and left channel together as IN in the schematic. Audio ground to battery ground

Comment: Try disconnecting the two channels, then driving with only a single channel. And turn the volume up as far as possible.

Comment: Look for information on "light organ" - that is a common name for lights controlled by music.

Comment: That circuit, as your reference explains, is biased so the transistor and LED are on with no signal present. Doesn’t seem too useful to me. I would think you’d want the LED to be off, and start lighting up with louder and louder signal, no? For that, just bias the transistor down to the point where it is barely off (base at about 0.5V) and positive swings of the incoming signal will start turning things on. Doesn’t matter that negative swings turn it back off – there’s enough persistence in LED to be able to view light. If you change R2 to about 30K you’ll be pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

Your signal averages at 0VDC, it does not rectify and filter the input signal. Then the average brightness is with its input at 0VDC.
You need a "peak detector" which rectifies the signal and filters the resulting DC voltage that represents the loudness of the input signal.
Here is my peak detector:
[image: peak detector]